# How to build an association using ecto and guardian

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Somehow I can't get this to work in **Phoenix / Ecto** with **Guardian**:

#### MeetingController#create

```
changeset = case Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(conn) do
    true ->
        Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn) # == existing user
        |> build_assoc(:meetings) # successfully builds a meeting with user_id
        |> Meeting.changeset_with_user(meeting_params) # removes user_id
     _ ->
        Meeting.changeset(%Meeting{}, meeting_params)
end
```

#### Meeting

```
schema "meetings" do
    field :title, :string
    field :description, :string

    belongs_to :user, User
end

def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:title], [:description])
end

def changeset_with_user(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> changeset(params)
    |> assoc_constraint(:user)
end
```

How can I insert a `meeting` with an associated `user`? Calling `build_assoc` correctly sets the `user_id`, but calling `changeset` removes the association again. The user is able to successfully authenticate. What am I missing here?

Comment: Should not it be `cast(params, [:title, :description, :user])`?

Answer (score 0):

See this [comment](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1824#issuecomment-262739006), `changeset` does not contain the associated properties directly, but through`changeset.data`.

> we will lift the other fields from changeset.data, including the user_id

So once inserted the association will be set correctly.